# Complex Numbers Binomial Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $a, b, n$ be any complex numbers.

For $(a\pm b)^n$, is there a binomial formula with a set number of finite terms that define this?

Comment: Only for $n =0,1,2,3,4,... $ you have a finite number of terms for general $a, b$. Complex exponents, even integer complex exponents, won't give you anything nice

Comment: @YuriyS In that case, is there a general form using a infinite set of terms where a, b, & n are complex numbers?

Comment: formally yes, we can always expand it in a series some way, we have to be careful about convergence though. To obtain the series it's better to transform the expression to the exponential form: $$e^{n \log(a \pm b)}$$

Comment: If you really want binomial series then compare the absolute values of $a$ and $b$ to determine which is smaller, and then use something like $a/b$ as a variable to get binomial series with an infinite number of terms. I think the usual formula should work even with complex $n$

Comment: @YuriyS Could you articulate on that thought by showing a working example?

Comment: The same as the binomial formula for the reals.

Comment: I never thought about it but if $a = re^{i\theta}$ and $b=se^{i\eta}$ then $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} r^ks^{n-k} e^{ik\theta + (n-k)\eta}$

Answer (score 0):

A working example, as the OP asked.

Let's consider the simplest possible case that is still relevant to the question:

$$x = (3+2i) ^i$$

The exact value is something awful, just check with Wolfram Alpha, if you want.

Can we use binomial series here?

Let's try.

$$x = ^? 3^i \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{i}{k} \left( \frac{2i}{3} \right)^k$$

First, let's deal with the prefix.

$$3^i = e^{i \log 3}=\cos(\log 3)+i \sin (\log 3)$$

The binomial coefficients are defined as follows:

$$  \binom{i}{k}={\frac {i(i-1)(i-2)\cdots (i-(k-1))}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}} $$

$$  \binom{i}{0}=1$$

$$  \binom{i}{1}=i$$

I suggest you try to calculate several terms of these series, add them, and then compare the results with the numerical value Wolfram Alpha gives.

For faster convergence we can use $13$ instead of $3$.